# Question marks in regular expressions

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I'm reading the [regular expressions reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) and I'm thinking about ? and ?? characters. Could you explain me with some examples their usefulness? I don't understand them enough.

thank you

Comment: What is your target programming language for using regexes? Regexes behave a little differently across languages.

Comment: I used regex in python, C#, php, perl, visual basic, grep.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The key difference between `?` and `??` concerns their *laziness*. `??` is lazy, `?` is not.

Let's say you want to search for the word "car" in a body of text, but you don't want to be restricted to just the singular "car"; you also want to match against the plural "cars".

Here's an example sentence:

`I own three cars.`

Now, if I wanted to match the word "car" *and I only wanted to get the string "car" in return*, I would use the lazy `??` like so:

`cars??`

This says, "look for the word car or cars; if you find either, return `car` and nothing more".

Now, if I wanted to match against the same words ("car" or "cars") *and I wanted to get the whole match in return*, I'd use the non-lazy `?` like so:

`cars?`

This says, "look for the word car or cars, and return either car or cars, whatever you find".

In the world of computer programming, lazy generally means "evaluating only as much as is needed". So the lazy `??` only returns as much as is needed to make a match; since the "s" in "cars" is optional, don't return it. On the flip side, non-lazy (sometimes called *greedy*) operations evaluate as much as possible, hence the `?` returns all of the match, including the optional "s".

Personally, I find myself using `?` as a way of making other regular expression operators lazy (like the `*` and `+` operators) more often than I use it for simple character optionality, but YMMV.

### See it in Code

Here's the above implemented in Clojure as an example:

```
(re-find #"cars??" "I own three cars.")
;=> "car"

(re-find #"cars?" "I own three cars.")
;=> "cars"
```

The item `re-find` is a function that takes its first argument as a regular expression `#"cars??"` and returns the first match it finds in the second argument `"I own three cars."`

Comment: Your `cars??` example is correct, but it returns the same results as if you had simply used `car`. You might need a different example to demonstrate the usefulness of ??.

Comment: @Justin, true, but yours has the same problem.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen - The third input string in my answer produces identical results when you leave out the `s??`, but the others do not. That's how it differs from leaving the optional element out of the pattern: by making the same pattern work for all three input strings.

Comment: @semperos
Hi , what if the character that I want to check for zero or one occurrence is  `?` itself ?

Comment: @VaradBhatnagar You would need to escape the `?` character in your regular expression. As an example in Clojure, if you wanted to match the string `foo?`, you could use `(re-find #"foo\?" "foo?")` where `\?` escapes the question mark in the regular expression so that it is treated literally, rather than as a regular expression operator.

Comment: @semperos - I don't think I understand the part where the program knows that `s` is somehow an optional character in `cars??`. What if I applied that for another language and searched for either `bil` or `biler` (the latter being plural of the first word)? Would the program then look for `bil` and `biler`, or would it look for `bile` (where `e` is too many letters) and `biler`, or is `s` somehow a special character coupled with the first `?` (e.i. `s?` asks if there's an `s` or no `s`)? Or maybe it asks whether any of the letters in `biler` is present, and so `b` would also return true?

Answer (score 92):

This is an excellent question, and it took me a while to see the point of the lazy `??` quantifier myself.

### ? - Optional (greedy) quantifier

The usefulness of `?` is easy enough to understand. If you wanted to find both `http` and `https`, you could use a pattern like this:

```regex
https?
```

This pattern will match both inputs, because it makes the `s` optional.

### ?? - Optional (lazy) quantifier

`??` is more subtle. It usually does the same thing `?` does. It doesn't change the true/false result when you ask: *"Does this input satisfy this regex?"* Instead, it's relevant to the question: *"Which part of this input matches this regex, and which parts belong in which groups?"* If an input could satisfy the pattern in more than one way, the engine will decide how to group it based on `?` vs. `??` (or `*` vs. `*?`, or `+` vs. `+?`).

Say you have a set of inputs that you want to validate and parse. Here's an (admittedly silly) example:

```
Input:       
http123
https456
httpsomething

Expected result:
Pass/Fail  Group 1   Group 2
Pass       http      123
Pass       https     456
Pass       http      something
```

You try the first thing that comes to mind, which is [this](http://rubular.com/r/ofZUqzWp58):

```regex
^(http)([a-z\d]+)$
```

```
Pass/Fail  Group 1   Group 2    Grouped correctly?
Pass       http      123        Yes
Pass       http      s456       No
Pass       http      something  Yes
```

They all pass, but you can't use the second set of results because you only wanted `456` in Group 2.

Fine, let's [try again](http://rubular.com/r/adPV5fUlov). Let's say Group 2 can be letters or numbers, but not both:

```regex
(https?)([a-z]+|\d+)
```

```
Pass/Fail  Group 1   Group 2   Grouped correctly?
Pass       http      123       Yes
Pass       https     456       Yes
Pass       https     omething  No
```

Now the second input is fine, but the third one is grouped wrong because `?` is greedy by default (the `+` is too, but the `?` came first). When deciding whether the `s` is part of `https?` or `[a-z]+|\d+`, *if the result is a pass either way,* the regex engine will always pick the one on the left.  So Group 2 loses `s` because Group 1 sucked it up.

To fix this, you make [one tiny change](http://rubular.com/r/AVkvgrtZaN):

```regex
(https??)([a-z]+|\d+)$
```

```
Pass/Fail  Group 1   Group 2    Grouped correctly?
Pass       http      123        Yes
Pass       https     456        Yes
Pass       http      something  Yes
```

Essentially, this means: *"Match `https` if you have to, but see if this still passes when Group 1 is just `http`."* The engine realizes that the `s` could work as part of `[a-z]+|\d+`, so it prefers to put it into Group 2.

Comment: In all your cases, `https??([a-z]+|\d+)` and `http([a-z]+|\d+)` (no s before capture at all) give the same matches and captures.  So I don't see how this is a meaningful example.

Comment: Your answer is excellent too. Actually I had problem only with ?? :-) and was looking what is different in opposite to ? .

Comment: @Matthew `http([a-z]+|\d+)` won't match `https(456)`. That's the difference.

Comment: @xralf, no.  They both match with exactly the same match and capture: [With ??](http://rubular.com/r/iIulNZ0ttz), [Without](http://rubular.com/r/iIulNZ0ttz).

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen - They work the same *for that input.* `http([a-z]+|\d+)$` will not match `https456`. `https??([a-z]+|\d+)$` will, and still have the expected results for `https456`. That's the difference.

Comment: @xralf - Note that I missed the $ before; it's necessary to capture properly from `https456`. See edit.

Comment: @Justin, yep, the demonstration is valid with the end anchor.

Comment: @JustinMorgan - Would `htt`, `ht` and `h` also return true with `https?`?

Comment: @Matt - No, because only the `s` is marked optional. The `http` part is required.

Answer (score 34):

### Some Other Uses of Question marks in regular expressions

Apart from what's explained in other answers, **there are still 3 more uses of Question Marks in regular expressions.**

1. **Negative Lookahead**

   Negative lookaheads are used if you want to
   match something not followed by something else. The negative
   lookahead construct is the pair of parentheses, with the opening
   parenthesis followed by a question mark and an exclamation point. `x(?!x2)`

   *example*

   - Consider a word `There`
   - Now, by default, the RegEx `e` will find the third letter `e` in word `There`.

     ```
     There
       ^
     ```
   - However if you don't want the `e` which is immediately followed by `r`, then you can use RegEx `e(?!r)`. Now the result would be:

     ```
     There
         ^
     ```
2. **Positive Lookahead**

   Positive lookahead works just the same. `q(?=u)` matches a `q` that
   is immediately followed by a `u`, without making the `u` part of the
   match. The positive lookahead construct is a pair of parentheses,
   with the opening parenthesis followed by a question mark and an
   equals sign.

   *example*

   - Consider a word `getting`
   - Now, by default, the RegEx `t` will find the third letter `t` in word `getting`.

     ```
     getting
       ^
     ```
   - However if you want the `t` which is immediately followed by `i`, then you can use RegEx `t(?=i)`. Now the result would be:

     ```
     getting
        ^
     ```
3. **Non-Capturing Groups**

   Whenever you place a Regular Expression in parenthesis`()`, they
   create a numbered capturing group. It stores the part of the string
   matched by the part of the regular expression inside the
   parentheses.

   If you do not need the group to capture its match, you can optimize
   this regular expression into

   ```
   (?:Value)
   ```

See also [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Answer (score 16):

`?` simply makes the previous item (character, character class, group) optional:

```
colou?r
```

matches "color" and "colour"

```
(swimming )?pool
```

matches "a pool" and "the swimming pool"

`??` is the same, but it's also lazy, so the item *will* be excluded if at all possible.  As those docs note, ?? is rare in practice.  I have never used it.

Comment: That is written in the reference too.

Comment: @xralf, is there anything that is still unclear after the docs and my examples?

Comment: @Matthew: You just reworded the reference doc, without explaining it. In particular the inclusion/exclusion from a match is a puzzling concept.

Comment: @Lars, sorry?  I did explain with examples.

Comment: @Matthew My comment may have crossed your edit; but see the other answers for good explanations of lazy vs. greedy.

Comment: @Lars, both of the `??` examples posted give the exact same results if you just drop the `element??` entirely (e.g. `car` instead of `cars??`).

Answer (score 1):

Running the test harness from Oracle documentation with the reluctant quantifier of the "once or not at all" match `X??` shows that it works as a guaranteed always-empty match.

```
$ java RegexTestHarness

Enter your regex: x?
Enter input string to search: xx
I found the text "x" starting at index 0 and ending at index 1.
I found the text "x" starting at index 1 and ending at index 2.
I found the text "" starting at index 2 and ending at index 2.

Enter your regex: x??
Enter input string to search: xx
I found the text "" starting at index 0 and ending at index 0.
I found the text "" starting at index 1 and ending at index 1.
I found the text "" starting at index 2 and ending at index 2.
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html

It seems identical to the empty matcher.

```
Enter your regex:     
Enter input string to search: xx
I found the text "" starting at index 0 and ending at index 0.
I found the text "" starting at index 1 and ending at index 1.
I found the text "" starting at index 2 and ending at index 2.

Enter your regex: 
Enter input string to search: 
I found the text "" starting at index 0 and ending at index 0.

Enter your regex: x??
Enter input string to search: 
I found the text "" starting at index 0 and ending at index 0.
```