# Matching word with period at end in regex

Tags: java, regex

Currently I am trying to see if there is a period, question mark or exclamation point at the end of a word in regex java. Here is what I'm trying:

```
if(Pattern.matches("[.!?]$", "test.")){
   // do stuff
}
```

Here I am just using the example `test.` which is a word and has a period at the end. This regex will not pick it up. I am using this regex because it will look for the three `.!?` at the end of the sentence since I am using `$`.

Comment: You forgot to test against anything proceeding the `[.!?]`

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: `test.` would fail, because it is not `?`, `!`, or `.`, followed by EOI. Per your pattern, it begins with those symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Pattern.matches` matches against the entire string. You can either modify your pattern, or use `Matcher.find` instead.

Option 1:

`Pattern.matches(".*[.!?]", "test.")`

Option 2:

`Pattern.compile("[.!?]$").matcher("test.").find()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Positive lookahead of Regular expression to search for `.!?` in front of a word. You can see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38893082/2815219) to learn more about **Positive and Negative Lookaheads**.

```
(\w+)(?=[.!?])
```

see this [link](https://regex101.com/r/eV0xH2/1)

**Use**

```
Pattern.matches("(\\w+)(?=[.!?])]", "test! tset some ohter! wordsome?")
```

**Matched Information**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-4]   `test`
MATCH 2
1.  [16-21] `ohter`
MATCH 3
1.  [23-31] `wordsome`
```