# Replace block of consecutive lines starting with same pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'd like to match (and replace with a custom replacement function) each block of *consecutive* lines that all start by `foo`. This nearly works:

```
import re

s = """bar6387
bar63287
foo1234
foohelloworld
fooloremipsum
baz
bar
foo236
foo5382
bar
foo879"""

def f(m):
    print(m)

s = re.sub('(foo.*\n)+', f, s)
print(s)
# <re.Match object; span=(17, 53), match='foo1234\nfoohelloworld\nfooloremipsum\n'>
# <re.Match object; span=(61, 76), match='foo236\nfoo5382\n'>
```

but it fails to recognize the last block, obviously because it is the last line and there is no `\n` at the end.

**Is there a cleaner way to match a block of one or multiple consecutive lines starting with same pattern `foo`?**

Comment: Try adding a `?` after your newline token to indicate either 0 or 1 of them, thus also matching a block that ends the file: `(foo.*\n?)+`

Comment: Actually your pattern matches any *foo*, even if it isn't at the start of a line.

Comment: @Adid that will also match a foo that is in the middle of a line

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, but I need more precisely a match/replace (with custom replacement function), and not a `re.split`. I tried your pattern in my `re.sub` but it doesn't work: there are many empty matches (?)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Oops that's right. How would you add this criteria ("starting by foo")? `^foo` did not seem to work in my case.

Comment: My apologies, I made a mistake. You could add the option to match either newline or end of string using `((?:^|\n)foo.*(?:$|\n))+`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, because in this case there is *one match per line*; instead I want one match/one call of replacement function *per whole block*.

Comment: like that: `(?m)^foo.*(?:\nfoo.*)*\n?`

Comment: It must be just a `re.sub(r'(?m)^foo.*(?:\nfoo.*)*', f, s)` or `re.sub(r'^foo.*(?:\nfoo.*)*', f, s, flags=re.M)`

Comment: Note you do not need `(?=\n|$)` after `.*` because `.` does not match line feed chars, so there is no need to check for the end of a line. Unless you want to consume the newline, then you would use something like `(?:\n|$)`, but it does  not look like you need that.

Comment: I'm with @Adid (add `^` anchor & `re.MULTILINE` if needed). Might be sufficient to use:  [`^(?:foo.*\n?)+`](https://regex101.com/r/GJw61i/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'(?m)^foo.*(?:\nfoo.*)*', f, s)
re.sub(r'^foo.*(?:\nfoo.*)*', f, s, flags=re.M)
```

where

- `^` - matches start of string (here, a start of any line due to `(?m)` or `re.M` option)
- `foo` - matches `foo`
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `(?:\nfoo.*)*` - zero or more sequences of a newline, `foo` and then the rest of the line.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/MJQiZb):

```py
import re

s = "bar6387\nbar63287\nfoo1234\nfoohelloworld\nfooloremipsum\nbaz\nbar\nfoo236\nfoo5382\nbar\nfoo879"
def f(m):
    print(m.group().replace('\n', r'\n'))

re.sub(r'(?m)^foo.*(?:\nfoo.*)*', f, s)
```

Output:

```
foo1234\nfoohelloworld\nfooloremipsum
foo236\nfoo5382
foo879
```

Comment: Thanks! What does `(?:...)*` mean exactly in regex?  I know `?` as [optional quantifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583579/question-marks-in-regular-expressions) but what is `?:...`?

Comment: @Basj A [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an `re.findall` approach:

```py
s = """bar6387
bar63287
foo1234
foohelloworld
fooloremipsum
baz
bar
foo236
foo5382
bar
foo879"""

lines = re.findall(r'^foo.*(?:\nfoo.*(?=\n|$))*', s, flags=re.M)
print(lines)
# ['foo1234\nfoohelloworld\nfooloremipsum',
   'foo236\nfoo5382',
   'foo879']
```

The above regex runs in multiline mode, and says to match:

```regex
^                     from the start of a line
foo                   "foo"
.*                    consume the rest of the line
(?:\nfoo.*(?=\n|$))*  match newline and another "foo" line, 0 or more times
```

**Edit:**

If you need to replace/remove these blocks, then use the same pattern with `re.sub` and a lambda callback:

```py
output = re.sub(r'^foo.*(?:\nfoo.*(?=\n|$))*', lambda m: "BLAH", s, flags=re.M)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
bar6387
bar63287
BLAH
baz
bar
BLAH
bar
BLAH
```

Comment: Thank you! Note: I need a `re.sub` with a custom replacement function, with one call of the function per *whole* block. Does it work too? (I will try in the meantime)

Comment: @Basj Check the bottom of my answer for an `re.sub` option.  You may place whatever replacement logic you want for each block inside the lambda function.

Comment: Note that `(?=\n|$)` is always true since the previous `.*` is greedy.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need a regex? Here is a [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) based approach:

```
from itertools import groupby
import re

# dummy example function
f = lambda x: '>>'+x.upper()+'<<'

out= '\n'.join(f(G) if (G:='\n'.join(g)) and k else G
               for k,g in groupby(s.split('\n'), lambda l: l.startswith('foo')))

print(out)
```

*NB. you don't **need** a regex, but you **can** also use a regex if needed to define the matching lines in `groupby`*

```
# using a regex to match the blocks:
out= '\n'.join(f(G) if (G:='\n'.join(g)) and k else G
               for k,g in  groupby(s.split('\n'),
                                   lambda l: bool(re.match('foo', l))
                                   ))
```

ouput:

```
bar6387
bar63287
>>FOO1234
FOOHELLOWORLD
FOOLOREMIPSUM<<
baz
bar
>>FOO236
FOO5382<<
barfoo
bar
>>FOO879<<
```